# Better file previewer than Gnome-Sushi in 13.10?

Tags: gnome

I'm looking for a better file previewer than gnome-sushi in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. I used to have gloobus preview, but that doesn't have a version yet for 13.10.. The thing that annoys me the most about sushi is that it doesn't continue to preview the rest of the folder after playing the file requested for preview (very annoying when listening to an album, with gloobus that went flawlessly). Anyone has a good alternative?

Comment: "Alternative" posts are considered *too broad*, so this should be closed. For more info take a look here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7947/62483

Comment: @Lucio - as this is about one sort of application, I doubt whether `it's like a normal software recommendation on steroids.`. :D

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you wanted, but...

### How to install gloobus previewer in Ubuntu 13.10

This installs the recent one for 13.04 *(probably)*

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gloobus-dev/gloobus-preview/ubuntu raring main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview gloobus-sushi
```

If it needs `libgtksourceview-3.0-0`, you can get it from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/gnome_3/raring/main/base/libgtksourceview-3.0-0), and install *(the 32bit version)* with:

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtksourceview3/libgtksourceview-3.0-0_3.7.90-0ubuntu1~raring2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i 'libgtksourceview-3.0-0_3.7.90-0ubuntu1~raring2_i386.deb'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, but I wasn't able to install libgtksourceview as the depencies it depends on could not be installed, any ideas? libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.2.4),libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.35.9), libgtk-3-0:i386 (>= 3.4.0), libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.18.0)

Comment: You can try UbuntuUpdates for those as well - e.g. [`libcairo2`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/main/base/libcairo2) [`libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/gnome_shell/saucy/main/base/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0)... Also [this `ppa`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gnome_shell?dist=saucy).